# ORA-00900 error in dbSendStatement() of 'RJDBC'

Tags: r, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to upload data from R to database, I used package 'RJDBC' to connect R to Oracle. The connection is set up and I am able to load data from Oracle to R. When I tried to insert data into a table in Oracle using `dbSendStatement()`:

```
sqlQuery_uploadResult<-function(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I){
  sprintf("INSERT INTO DEMAND_FCAST (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I) VALUES (TO_DATE('%s','DD-MON-YY hh24:mi:ss'),%1.4f,%5.2f,%2.0f,%1.4f,%5.2f,%2.0f,%2.0f)",A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I)
}

dbSendStatement(conn,sqlQuery_uploadResult(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I))
```

I got an error message:

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(md, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set meta data for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set meta data for INSERT INTO DEMAND_FCAST (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I) VALUES (TO_DATE('17-Oct-16 13:35:45','DD-MON-YY hh24:mi:ss'),0.1160,700,36,0.4037,965,35, 1) in dbSendQuery (ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
)
```

However, I checked the table in Oracle, the record I tried to insert **is in the table**, is there anyone has any clue why does this error turn out and how to deal with this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems like the data is being inserted into my table, but I feel like it would be sloppy to continue using my code without understanding why there's an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue. I tried `dbExecute()` and `dbSendQuery()` and got a similar error. A colleague suggested that I use `dbSendUpdate()` and it executed without error.

Comment: Yes, thx for your answer. I am also using dbSendUpdate() now and it works well.

Comment: Still valid problem / answer in March 2017